# How to update Trac changelog via XML-RPC plugin

Tags: xml-rpc, trac, changelog

I am trying to manage a trac instance from PHP using XML-RPC and I am stuck at updating ticket comments (a.k.a. ticket changelog).

I can retrieve the changelog by querying the RPC service with `ticket.changeLog` and I get a list of all the ticket's comments. However, there is nothing in [the docs of the XML-RPC plugin](https://trac-hacks.org/rpc) about how to update a single changelog entry.

I tried sending a `ticket.update` query with a comment that has the same timestamp but edited content, but it was still added as a new changelog entry.

If anyone has any clue they'll get a lot of gratitude filled thoughts! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TracXMLRPC doesn't yet support editing the ticket changelog. There hasn't been much work done to the plugin since editing the ticket changelog was added as a Trac feature in 0.12. See [#8882](https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/8882).